# Soap Request : 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, soap, web

This is my code it is in vb.net .  I did'nt get response from soap request , i have no idea what is the wrong with this code , its showing 500 Internal Server Error.

```
Dim webRequest__1 As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://login.twinfield.com/webservices/session.asmx?wsdl")
Dim httpRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(webRequest__1, HttpWebRequest)

httpRequest.Method = "POST"
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action='http://www.twinfield.com/Logon'"
httpRequest.Host = "login.twinfield.com"
httpRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction:https://login.twinfield.com/webservices/session.asmx")
httpRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11
httpRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

Dim requestStream As Stream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream()
'Create Stream and Complete Request             

Dim streamWriter As New StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.ASCII)
' <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' xmlns:twin='http://www.twinfield.com/'>

Dim soapRequest As New StringBuilder("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' xmlns:twin='http://www.twinfield.com/'><soap:Header/><soap:Body><twin:Logon><twin:user>dgf</twin:user> <twin:password>cfg</twin:password><twin:organisation>dfd</twin:organisation></twin:Logon></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>")
'soapRequest.Append(" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" ")
'soapRequest.Append("xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""><soap:Body>")
'soapRequest.Append("<GetMyName xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/""><name>Sam</name></GetMyName>")
'soapRequest.Append("</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>")

streamWriter.Write(soapRequest.ToString())
streamWriter.Close()
'Get the Response    

Dim htttpresponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(httpRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
'Dim wr As HttpWebResponse = CType(httpRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
'DirectCast(httpRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Dim srd As New StreamReader(htttpresponse.GetResponseStream())
Dim resulXmlFromWebService As String = srd.ReadToEnd()
'Return resulXmlFromWebService
```

Answer (score 0):

To call a soap web service, I think it is better to add the service url as a web reference (i.e. name as twinfield) in visual studio. Then you can use the service as a function as below.

```
twinfield.Session s = new twinfield.Session();
twinfield.LogonAction ac;
string cl = "";
twinfield.LogonResult k = s.Logon("dsfa", "Sadfsa", "sdfas", out ac, out cl);
```